# Building a MEAN App using Angular 2 and Angular-CLI

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I'm trying to work my way through building a MEAN app using Angular 2 and building Angular with the Angular CLI.

My GitHub repo is [here](https://github.com/gh0st/ng2do-mean-app). It builds and serves and lints without issue but when you try to visit the page I get a handful of reference errors like the ones below

[image: screenshot of errors on serve]

Like it can't find the references to the .js files that are built when I run `ng build --prod --output-path my-app`.

I'm not sure if it might have anything to do with my routes because in my `routes/index.js` I have

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index.html');
});
```

But this shouldn't prevent my scripts from being loaded, should it?

Comment: I think  `npm build --prod` is generating a new hash on the filename for every build.. may be ? Since `index.html` file has the references to what was previously generated, the new computed file name might not be the same and so not found... Let us know.

Comment: I fixed it. Pushed the fix to github but I'll answer it here when I get back on a machine.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't correctly serving my static files.
My statics were still being loaded via

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public/')));
```

When they should have been

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public/my-app/')));
```

Simple solution...overlooked it.
Just in case there's anyone else out there having the same issue.